# Postgresql PG::ConnectionBad + working with Github project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on rails. Recently I am working on a project done halfway by another programmer. What I did was I cloned his repository and installed all the required bundles and gems etc so that I can run development locally. It used to work all the time when I run rails server and visit localhost:3000

However, today I set up a dual boot Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1. Then, I followed the exact same process as before to install required gems and set up the environment.

However, this time, when I run rails server and visit localhost:3000
I run into the following problem:

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "xx.xx.xx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 6543?
```

This is weird, because it used to work without me configuring anything on the database.yml.

If I start a new rails project and do

```
rails new projectName -d postgresql
```

it works fine after I edited the database.yml file to the correct credential.

So my question is, if I cloned a repository and started to collaborate with another programmer on the project, how should I set up the postgresql database for me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't told us the answer to the question in the error message. Is the server running on that IP and port? And how did you verify this?

Comment: I have not found the answer to the error message. In the database.yml file, the port and host is the same as those shown in the error message. However, i want to run them in localhost, do i have to change any setting?

Comment: Well either the database is accessible at those settings or it isn't. If it is, you have some other fault. If it isn't then you need to change either the database or your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It is the host address, I was using the wrong host address because my co-programmer changed the address. So, ya, if the host is correct in the database, then you should be able to see the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make possible for everyone to have their own local database configuration, consider to create **database.yml.example** file. Some people think that it's a bad practice, from my experience, it's very handy.

How to make it:

1. Rename *database.yml* to *database.yml.example.*
2. Commit it
3. Add *database.yml* to *.gitignore* and commit this change.
4. Make a copy of *database.yml.example* and rename it back into *database.yml*.

Now when someone will clone your repo, she will have to create her own *database.yml* file from *.example*. So everyone will have his own database configuration.